# How to filter search by attribute only if it exists using ElasticSearch and Tire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, elasticsearch, tire

Right now I wrote

```
Tire.search INDEX_NAME do
  query do
    filtered do
      query { string term }
      filter :or, { missing: { field: :app_id } },
                  { terms: { app_id: app_ids } }
    end
  end
end.results.to_a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well returning items that either have no app_id or one that matches your terms sounds like a job for an or filter - I'd try

```
filter :or, [
    {:not => {:exists => {:field => :app_id}}},
    {:terms => {:app_id => app_ids}}
  ]
```

Comment: You solution has any advantages over my ``missing`` filter? 
``filter :or, { missing: { field: :app_id } }``

Comment: Don't think so, although your missing thing easn't there when I wrote my post